# Setting up LaTeX in VS Code?

Tags: miktex, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to set up LaTeX in VS Code.

I have installed MiKTeX and I am able to create TeX files and pdfs using TeXworks.

I have installed the TeX workshop extension in Visual Studio Code. Yet I still cannot use TeX workshop within Visual Studio Code. I often get this error:

```
Recipe terminated with fatal error: spawn latexmk ENOENT
```

Another error I get is:

```
Cannot view file PDF file. File not found: C:Users\myname\Documents\Programs\VSCode\LaTeX\LaTeX workshop.pdf
```

What can I do to get this to work? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have found a solution.

I need to install `latexmk` (I have done this using the MiKTeX console).

Then, to run `latexmk` I have installed `strawberry perl`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your knowledge: if you want, there are some very useful plugins for VSC that are downloadable online (and especially open source).
They will allow you to work very comfortably in LaTeX, and there are many feature they can give you!
This is the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) of the plugin I use: it's a very popular one and really easy to use.
Enjoy you LaTeX journey!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was attempting to set up LaTeX workshop with MiKTeX and was having some trouble. I ended up downloading something called strawberry perl and I also downloaded latexmk using the MiKTeX console. Now it works well though. Do you know if there is any way to stop the notifications you get from the extension when your typing something? Whenever I am in hte middle of typing a new command LaTeX workshop tells me that there is an erroe till it realizes that I am not done with the command yet.

Comment: You're welcome! I had to install strawberry perl too because it's required to make some MikTek scripts usable by the user. About your question to be honest I don't know how to help you (at the moment) because I don’t know what you’re talking about and I have too little infos about it. In any case, I would advise you to open a new question here or in stack overflow to get rid of your problem ;P

Comment: Oh. Well now that I have installed latexmk using the MikTeX console and also strawberry perl everything works great!!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error "Cannot view file PDF file. File not found:", but the issue was that before viewing the pdf you actually need to generate it. You generate the pdf file with the "build latex project" button, the small one in the upper right corner with a triangle in green. Once generated you just click on the "view latex pdf file" button (right upper corner).